# Problems with Feature Branches In Git

Tags: git

The following description is looking for help with improving my day to day workflow with git and solving an issue I'm not having with additional work.

Let's say I create a remote feature branch from Jira. Then I track it so that it creates a local copy of that remote branch on my local repo. After I complete it that feature, I push that remote version of that feature branch and then make a pull request into the remote development branch. My issue is I've been given the green light to go in and refactor code because this project code is all over the place. However, if I create a branch off of my local dev its not going to be my changes from the local feature branches that I've done. Should I push my local feature branches into my local dev branch?

```
Branches

Local

   - Development
   - Feature 1
   - Feature 2

Remote

   - Master
   - Development
   - Feature 1
   - Feature 2
```

Comment: If you merge your changes into your local development branch before they've merged upstream, you won't be able to submit pull requests because your history and upstream history will be different.  If you're certain that your feature branches will merge upstream before you need to submit a new PR go ahead, but it's safest if you start your changes from a branch that reflects the state of the upstream branch you'll be targeting with pull requests.

Comment: just pull your dev branch

Comment: @AlexanDo I pull from the local dev branch or remote?

Comment: `git checkout Development` then `git pull`

so you pull remote Dev from local

Comment: I agree with @Alexan, pull dev and then branch from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best course of action would be to ask your project lead what they would do. That way, the fault of doing it wrongly won't lie with you. :)

If that's not an option, I would try to follow the [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) approach. What this means in detail comes down to what you mean by this statement:

> I've been given the green light to go in and refactor code because this project code is all over the place.

Does this mean refactoring everything that's currently in the `Development` branch? If so, your approach should be as follows:

1. Create a new feature branch that branches off of `Development`
2. Using that feature branch, refactor the code base
3. Create a pull request to merge your feature branch into `Development`

> However, if I create a branch off of my local dev its not going to be my changes from the local feature branches that I've done.

That's true, and you have two options here:

- Do the refactoring of `Development` first. As soon as that is done, refactor the code for your new feature on your local feature branch, then open a pull request to merge it into `Development`.
- Open the pull request to merge it into `Development` first - as soon as it is merged into `Development`, you can begin the refactoring of `Development` (which then includes refactoring the code introduced for your new feature as well, of course).

The former approach might save you some work in terms of refactoring, but the latter approach will get the feature out quicker. Once again, depending on how much time is necessary to refactor the code base, this question might be suited for your project lead.